# Why am I unable to affect the H2 titles using CSS in this instance?

Tags: css, firebug

I have a slideshow, and I was able to get the description to show up in yellow, which I want.

But the title (H2) above the description is invisible, unless you hover over it.  I currently have this as my CSS:

```
.slideshow_container { background: #000; }
.slideshow_container a { text-decoration: none; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_slide { margin-right: 2px; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_slide_text h2 { color: #FFFFFF; text-align: left; 
font-size: 1.3em; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_slide_text p { color: #FFFF00; font-weight: bold; 
text-align: left; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_slide_image { }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_slide_video { }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_description { background: #000; width: 100%; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_description h2  { color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 1.3em; 
text-align: left; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_description p  { color: #FFFF00; font-size: 1.1 em; 
font-weight: bold; text-align: left; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_description a  { color: #FFFF00; font-weight: bold; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_transparent { filter: alpha(opacity = 50); opacity: 0.5; }
.slideshow_container .slideshow_transparent:hover { filter: alpha(opacity = 80); opacity: 
0.8; }
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow_container slideshow_container_slideshow-jquery-image-gallery-custom-
styles_1" style="height: 600px; max-width: 660px;" data-session-id="0"><div
class="slideshow_controlPanel slideshow_transparent"><ul><li
class="slideshow_togglePlay"></li></ul></div><div
class="slideshow_button slideshow_previous slideshow_transparent"></div><div
class="slideshow_button slideshow_next slideshow_transparent"></div><div
class="slideshow_pagination"><div
class="slideshow_pagination_center"></div></div><div
class="slideshow_content" style="display: none;"><div
class="slideshow_view"><div
class="slideshow_slide slideshow_slide_image"> <a
target="_self" > <img src="http://www.occupyhln.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Audrey-    
Edmunds.jpg" alt="Audrey Edmunds" width="1000" height="588" /> </a><div
class="slideshow_description slideshow_transparent">
<h2><a target="_self" >Audrey Edmunds</a></h2>
<p><a target="_self" >Here, Audrey Edmunds poses at the John C. Burke Correctional Center 
in Waupun, Wis., 10 years into serving her 18-year conviction and sentence for shaking a 
baby to death, while babysitting. She was freed in Feb., 2008 after an appeals court said 
new research into the syndrome cast doubt on her guilt. According to Northwestern 
University's Center on Wrongful Convictions, experts asserted that symptoms they once 
thought were proof of Shaken Baby Syndrome can be from other causes, including accidents, 
illness, infection, old injuries, and congenital defects.</a></p>
</div></div><div style="clear: both;"></div></div>
```

The paragraph part seems to be working well, and the descriptions are showing up yellow.  But I'd like to get the heading to show up white, so it stands out.  Currently, you have to hover over the titles just above the paragraph in order to see them.

You can see the sideshow on [this particular page](http://www.occupyhln.org/exonerated-from-prison-and-death-row/) ... I've tried to firebug it, but nothing seems to work.

Any guidance in this regard would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post the HTML here.

Comment: Use a DOM inspector to make sure that you've got the proper class/element chain in css. e.g. `<div class="slideshow_container"><div class="slideshow_description"><h2>`. Your html in the page is a total mess and unreadable as is.

Comment: Page checked: http://www.occupyhln.org/exonerated-from-prison-and-death-row/  ||  Total errors found: 52 (Parsing: 5, HTML: 47)  ||  Total warnings found:6 (HTML: 6)  ||  (X)HTML used for this page:HTML 5.1

Comment: This needs to be re-tag i guess.

Comment: Thanks j08691.  I included the html and css.  Marc B, the html is minified, so it may look like a mess.  Milche, it's really just a blank page with a slideshow added, so I don't know why I'd be getting errors.  What do you suggest I use for tags instead of the ones I have there?  Thank you all for attempting to help!

Answer (score 2):

It's all about specificity Id override any class.

you have a rule `#content h2 a, #content h2 a:visited` which as i said override your `.slideshow_container .slideshow_description h2` selector

Read more about specificity [Here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this style `#content h2 a` is taking precedence and overriding your white with `#111111`

Since you use an `id` with that stlye, it is overriding this style `.slideshow_container_style-dark .slideshow_description a`

You should also not that the text you have in the `h2` has link tag (`a`). That's why your snippet above is not recognized: `.slideshow_container .slideshow_description h2`

To fix this, you can try this: `#content .slideshow_container .slideshow_description h2 a`. It's kind of ugly, but should work.